# ReactNative Enable thermal overload error reporting

Tags: react-native, reload

It is most likely that you see this error because you update to Redux 2.x and React 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically

```
/**
 * Created by yusen on 2017/4/11.
 */

'use strict'

import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './reducer'
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist'

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore)

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, enhancer)
    if(module.hot) {
        console.log('hot reload detected',reducer);
        if (module.hot.accept) {
            console.log('accept2', module.hot.accept);
        }
        module.hot.accept(() => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('./reducer').default
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
            console.log("accept2223", nextRootReducer)
        })
    }
    // persistStore(store)
    // return compose(createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState))
    return store
}
```

I have tried to modify the store issue, but every time I save the modified file, I still report the error above. After ignoring that error, I still cannot render the modified content to the page in real time, and the page remains the original content.
I hope to solve the problem of error reporting